# redirecting STDERR in jruby

Tags: jruby, stderr

I'm trying to redirect STDERR to a file for a jruby program that runs as a daemon. I've done this in MRI before with no issue, but I seem to be missing some piece of the puzzle in jruby.

```
log = File.new('/home/my_user/test_log.log', "w")
$stderr.reopen log
$stderr.puts "writing to log!"

require 'some_broken_thing'
```

log contents in MRI (2.0.0-p0):

```
/path/to/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- some_broken_thing (LoadError)
  from /path/to/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
  from test.rb:5:in `<main>'
writing to log!
```

log contents in jruby (1.7.4):

```
writing to log!
```

I'm just trying to ensure that silly things like broken requires or unmet dependencies get logged somewhere instead of getting fired off to the console. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I call $stderr.reopen, the error output from the broken require doesn't show up in the console, which is good, but it never shows up in the file, which isn't so good.

Comment: Just found the follow-up on this as a jruby bug https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1082 .Thanks for raising!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to close this out. As [inger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174284/inger) pointed out, this was fixed in http://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1082